Advantage of using Either<Maybe<int>, InformationEntries> over nullable and exceptions
I don’t see any significant advantage in using Either/Maybe/InformationEntries over simple nullable types with exceptions, especially in .NET 8 / C# 12, where the compiler handles nullable types very effectively.
To me, this approach seems non-idiomatic and results in unnecessary boilerplate code. Rather than fearing exceptions and trying to avoid them, I prefer to embrace them. Actively throwing exceptions and properly integrating them into logging and user-facing messages/prompts seems more efficient and integrates better with third-party-tools (e.g. logging) and API's.
Am I missing something here: ?

"Either/Maybe/InformationEntries"  - From where do you get those types?

"Rather than fearing exceptions and trying to avoid them, I prefer to embrace them." You're still free to do so. Either<>, Maybe<>, etc are continuing in the implementation of common functional programming paradigms as first-class features in C# at large. That's like saying "LINQ's SelectMany() seems non-idiomatic. Why wouldn't I just use nested for loops?".

Also: there is a fraction of devs that consider control flow by exception to be an anti-pattern. There are different reasons for and against that and their applicability also may depend on the environment and use-case.

"there are less bots around, trying to sneak as many credits as possible by closing anything they don't understand." curation by voting to close etc. does not provide any reputation (reputation, not "credits"), it is done for the good of the community and this site. In any case, meta-commentary like that doesn't belong in a question, so I rolled back your edit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/softwarearchitecture/comments/1fkmq0d/advantage_of_using_eithermaybeint/

Either (or any equivalent type that represents "one of the two types") type is very useful for methods "with possible failure". Usually, when something goes wrong, we throw exception instead of returning "failure value", which would be probably of a different type than is returned from method.
Throwing exceptions is not performant, so it is better to return some "failure value" from method. But there is this type conflict in our way - and this is solved by types like Either, which mean "one of two types", which in our scenario would mean "either successful value or error".
I've run simple benchmark - with failure signalled by exception and by value in tuple. Here are some results showing what I have meant:
| Method                | Mean          | Error       | StdDev      | Median        |
|---------------------- |--------------:|------------:|------------:|--------------:|
| BenchWithoutException |     0.0348 ns |   0.0305 ns |   0.0510 ns |     0.0105 ns |
| BenchWithException    | 6,537.7211 ns | 142.0377 ns | 402.9373 ns | 6,383.6174 ns |

The code under test:
public class Tests
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchWithoutException()
    {
        var result = WithoutException();
        if (result.Item2) { } // do something on failure
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchWithException()
    {
        try
        {
            WithException();
        }
        catch
        {
            // do something on failure
        }
    }

    static int WithException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    static (int, bool) WithoutException()
    {
        return (0, false);
    }
}


"Throwing exceptions is not performant": i agree, but i don't think it is a question of performance. Because exceptions should happen rarely in unexpected situations. To return multiple things, just use an object as return-value.
